# How can I achieve AngularJS sub view page routing concept?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a question on routing. I have attached on sample Image in the first reply of the question which functionality I want to achieve.

I have a single page app with ng-view tag. Under ng-view, I have 3 links: :Link1, Link2, and Link3. Clicking on each link should show the results on the right side of the screen under the ng-view only. I want to change my url as well, eg: `websitename/home/link1`, `websitename/home/link2`, `websitename/home/link3`, based on a default url of `websitename/home`. I don't want to refresh the left side panel while changing the links.

How can I achieve this feature with AngularJS? Should I use ngInclude/ngDirectives/ngview/ngSwitch? I am totally clueless. From online tutorials, I've learned that I should not use multiple ng-view tags for the same application. Is it true?

Moreover, I can't move ng-view to right hand panel because in my header there are many page navigations. This view is one of them.

Comment: Could you possibly include your code? It's hard to suggest what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ntfxgz.jpg

Comment: I didn't write code yet. I want to know what is the correct implementation for this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make child url for a parent url and then access that child url so that the view for that child url can render under the view of the parent url.
For this you can use ui.router module.
Ex:

$stateProvider.state({
   name: "parent-view",
   url: "/parentView",
   templateUrl: "templates/parentView.html"
});

$stateProvider.state({
   name: "parent-child-view",
   url: "/childView",
   templateUrl: "templates/childView.html",
   parent: "parent-view"
});

now from the controller you have to call $state.transitionTo("parent-child-view");